# Union Operation For std::set

Tags: c++

Is there no function in the standard library like this?

```
set<T> set::union(set<T> other)
```

Or even this?

```
set<T> getUnion(set<T> a, set<T> b)
```

`set_union` is the right function in name only. It can operate on `vector` also, which means it may not be as efficient as a `set`-only function.

I **am not appending. *Appending destroys the original set*. I want a *new* set representing the union.**

Comment: @Dlotan I'm not trying to append. I want a new set representing the union.

Comment: so someone there talked about: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/

Comment: @ChrisRedford See the second answer of the duplicate, `set_union`

Comment: @ChrisRedford When you append, you get a union.

Comment: @DanielFrey I was aware of `set_union` before asking and it is the right function in name only. It can operate on vectors also, which means it may not be as efficient as a `set`-only function.

Comment: @juanchopanza When you append, you destroy the original set.

Comment: @ChrisRedford Don't underestimate the efficiency of [`set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union), as it requires ***sorted*** ranges (as given by a `std::set`). It is, in fact, linear to the number of elements in both ranges, I don't see how you can hope for more.

Comment: @ChrisRedford Well then you copy the original into another one.

Comment: @DanielFrey `set_union` has to insert into an output set, right? And these insertions are log(N).

Comment: @juanchopanza Good point, but OP want a new `set` which is the union of both existing sets. Since the inserts are in-order, `set_union` might even use a hint to insert after `end()` in each case. I don't know if it can get any better than that, but my point is that `set_union` is not a stupid O(n^2) algorithm :)

Comment: @keyser that ignores the cost of inserting into the output container.

Comment: @DanielFrey That is a good point. I might go and profile this if I find a spare moment.

Comment: in c++ 17, you can get a merge method, which would be great https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/merge . But the Complexity
N*log(size()+N)), where N is source.size() , is the same as you just insert it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the two-iterator `std::set::insert` template for this:

```
template <typename T>
std::set<T> getUnion(const std::set<T>& a, const std::set<T>& b)
{
  std::set<T> result = a;
  result.insert(b.begin(), b.end());
  return result;
}
```

---

**Note**: Following some of the comments suggesting I take one of the parameters by value because I need a copy anyway, I chose this implementation to avoid disallowing RVO, which is not allowed when returning  parameter taken by value. To better deal with rvalue arguments, overloads of this function taking rvalue reverences and leveraging move semantics could be provided.

Comment: wouldn't `std::set_union` be more efficient?

Comment: Pro tip: when you're passing a const reference to a function then immediately taking a copy of it, just pass by value instead.

Comment: @MarkRansom I am returning the copy, and I don't want to inhibit RVO. Copying the argument and returning it would inhibit it. So I don't think the pro tip is a good one in this case.

Comment: @sehe I'm not sure it is. It is linear in comparisons, but each set insertion is log(N). Or did I miss something?

Comment: @juanchopanza `insert` is guaranteed to attempt insertion, so it could be considerably more costly if you did e.g. `b = a; a.insert(b.begin(), b.end());` (it's likely up to QoI though)

Comment: @juanchopanza why it inhibit RVO ? use some thing like this : http://paste.ofcode.org/uhGfDnXeum8HMwc65dM5Qn

Comment: @omid Yes, that inhibits RVO. Otherwise I would have suggested it in my answer.

Comment: @omid but make `b` by `const&`.

Comment: @omid See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444485/why-is-rvo-disallowed-when-returning-a-parameter

Comment: @juanchopanza, thanks for the link, I was curious too. Just goes to show that you can't rely on *any* rules of thumb.

Comment: @juanchopanza each set insertion is O(log(N)) where N is the current size, but this is repeated b.size() times. According to cppreference.com, this insert is "often implemented as a loop that calls the overload (3) with end() as the hint; they are optimized for appending a sorted sequence (such as another set) whose smallest element is greater than the last". Using the position after the last inserted element would be a better choice for the hint, since it would perform just as well in the given case while also making your usage linear rather than NlogN.

Answer (score 1):

There's [`std::set_union`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/).

[The example from that page](https://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/#example) uses vectors and arrays, so it's pretty versatile:

> ```
> // set_union example
> #include <iostream>     // std::cout
> #include <algorithm>    // std::set_union, std::sort
> #include <vector>       // std::vector
>
> int main () {
>   int first[] = {5,10,15,20,25};
>   int second[] = {50,40,30,20,10};
>   std::vector<int> v(10);                      // 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
>   std::vector<int>::iterator it;
>
>   std::sort (first,first+5);     //  5 10 15 20 25
>   std::sort (second,second+5);   // 10 20 30 40 50
>
>   it=std::set_union (first, first+5, second, second+5, v.begin());
>                                                // 5 10 15 20 25 30 40 50  0  0
>   v.resize(it-v.begin());                      // 5 10 15 20 25 30 40 50
>
>   std::cout << "The union has " << (v.size()) << " elements:\n";
>   for (it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
>     std::cout << ' ' << *it;
>   std::cout << '\n';
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Output:

```
The union has 8 elements:
 5 10 15 20 25 30 40 50
```

Comment: That does not really work for `std::set` though.