# Inherit Initialization Syntax from std::set or std::map

Tags: c++, stl

The standard library neglects to implement basic operations for `std::set` and `std::map` like

```
set<T> set<T>::getUnion(set<T> other)
```

and

```
bool map<K,V>::contains(K key)
```

I know there are verbose and/or indirect workarounds for these methods but if I want my code to be maximally readable and expressive, I'm going to have to inherit from the STL, write my own `Set` and `Map` classes, and implement them myself. And yes, I'm aware of the sermonizing against doing this but the fact is the STL is incomplete.

I've done this but now I can't initialize my new classes using, e.g.,

```
Set<int> s = {1,2,3,4};
```

How do I inherit these initializers from the `std` classes?

Comment: `bool map::contains(K key)` is useful only in very narrow use cases. Most of the time, you want to access the value given a key.

Comment: So is `vector::back()`. Most of the time you just want to `push_back`, iterate, or access by index. But that didn't stop the STL authors from specifying `back`. The reality is, any operation implemented for a Python `dict` should be implemented for `map`. The same goes for Python `set`. The question isn't frequency of use but the expected mathematical, intuitive, and logical structure for what the data structure represents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact that publically inheriting from standard library containers is considered to be a bad idea, you can "inherit" the constructors:

```
template <typename T>
struct Set : std::set<T>
{
  using std::set<T>::set; // "inherit" the constructors.
};
```

then

```
Set<int> s{1,6,4,3,3,9};
```

Note that a better approach might be to implement functions:

```
template <typename C>
bool contains(const C& container, const typename C::key_type& key)
{
  return container.count(key);
}
```

and [similarly for the union of sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437015/union-operation-for-stdset/23437066#23437066).

Comment: Why not make `contains` generic for 8 containers: `template<typename C> bool contains(const C& c,const typename C::key_type& k) { return c.count(k); }`?

Comment: Inheriting from standard containers is discouraged because of the potential for slicing or improper destruction, which won't be a problem if you don't have any added data members or virtual functions and your derived destructor is default. Of course that means you're hoping the maintainer who comes after you knows those rules too.

Comment: @MarkRansom Agreed, but it won't be a problem as long as you don't try to `delete` via a base class pointer. But private inheritance seems reasonably safe to me.

Comment: I get `error: ‘std::set<T>::set’ names constructor` when I add `using std::set<T>::set;`.

Comment: @ChrisRedford You need C++11 support for that. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/pJK9bp). Without C++11, you have to do it by hand.

Comment: I'm using C++11: `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -g -Wall -DTRUE=1 -DFALSE=0 -DNULL=0  -g main.cpp`

Comment: @ChrisRedford It could be that your version of gcc is not recent enough. I just tried it with gcc 4.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

For `gcc 4.7.x`, you have to call the `initializer_list` constructor for the `set` or `map`:

```
template <typename T>
class Set : public set<T> {
public:
    Set(){
        set<T>::set();
    }
    Set(initializer_list<T> iList) {
        set<T>::set(iList);
    }
};
```

Allowing

```
Set<int> s = {1,2,3,4};
```

But after much trial and error, I can't find a way to do this for `std::map`.

Also, it disables all the other constructors, requiring me to reimplement them, a task I'm not up to yet, so I'm just giving up on initializer lists for now. Anyone is welcome to submit an answer that reimplements all the constructors as `Set` and I'll choose it as the answer.

Comment: You should probably add your very specific requirements to the question. Basically, you need something that supports C++11 minus inherited constructors.

Comment: Yeah, it is looking like just using gcc 4.8 would solve these problems. Then I could use your answer, which I have verified works on a different machine with an updated compiler.