# Can a return value be optimized out in case it is dependent in function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++17, return-value-optimization

For the following code, I get in C++17:

```
move ctor
dtor
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dtor
```

Is this a possible output as well? i.e the move c'tor be elided and object be constructed in the caller side? Yes or No? And why?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dtor
```

This is the code:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; }
};

Foo passit(Foo f) {
    return f;
}

int main() {
    Foo f = passit(Foo{});
    std::cout << std::string(80, '-') << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: No, function parameters being returned are not candidates for elision.

Comment: Even if passit would somehow forward the rvalue reference to foo. It would be converted to an lvalue by giving it a name on the first line of main. After which the tempporary passed to passit goes out of scope because the statement ended.

Comment: [Why are by-value parameters excluded from NRVO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009278/why-are-by-value-parameters-excluded-from-nrvo) and [Why is RVO disallowed when returning a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444485/why-is-rvo-disallowed-when-returning-a-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

> In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which **isn't a function parameter** or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value optimization."

Furthermore, it's hard to see how the compiler could decide on this line that the `Foo` object should be constructed at the address of `f`, without knowing what happens within `passit()`, because this is effectively what would be required to optimise that copy out:

```
Foo f = passit(Foo{});
```

Comment: Yes, but could it technically be constructed at the address of f, or is anything in the spec preventing this?

Comment: The spec explicitly prevents it for function parameters.  I don't know the exact reasons why.  My suspicion is that it would be hard to implement.